# Запрос MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть некоторая таблица comments, и таблица лайков (поля ид записи, и лайк/дислайк). Скажите, какой нужно сделать запрос, чтобы при извлечении  комментариев, можно было получить количество лайков/дислайков как $comments['likes'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.*, sum(l.likes) as likes 
from comments c
JOIN likes l ON l.entry_id = c.id
```

Вот примерно так..  Могу ошибаться, потому что чисто из головы писал

Comment: `count(l.likes) as likes`
Можно и так ещё...

Comment: Судя по вопросу, в l.likes может быть отрицательное число, 0 или положительное число (ну я бы так сделал: 0 - не оценивали, дислайк - -1 от поля, лайк - + 1 к полю.  Или вообще сделал бы два разных поля)..  count посчитает количество полей, а надо сумму..